# send post data from javascript to python server

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, server

I am trying to record audio with JavaScript and send it to a Python server. As for now, I have run it and the record works fine. Using AJAX to post and get data, I am trying to pass it, but it doesn't work to send to Python.

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
function submit(blob) {
  var reader = new window.FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    base64data = reader.result;
    console.log(base64data);
    fd.append('file', base64data, 'audio.ogg');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/',
      data: fd,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Python Server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')

    def home():

        return render_template("index.html")

     @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
     def get_data():
             with open('./audio.ogg', 'wb') as f:
                 f.write(request.data)
             f.close()
             print("FILE CLOSED")
             return render_template("index.html")

    if __name__ == '__main__':

      app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you're trying to send a string as a file, you should be sending a file/blob.
See Below

```
function submit(blob) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', blob, 'audio.ogg');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/',
      data: fd,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

In you server side code you should use `request.files` to access the uploaded files.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')

    def home():

        return render_template("index.html")

     @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
     def get_data():
             request.files["file"].save('./audio.ogg')
             print("FILE CLOSED")
             return render_template("index.html")

    if __name__ == '__main__':

      app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Maybe my question wasnt so specific..when the record is finished and it played the audio...it doesnt return something to python server...maybe its something about my html file?